# Cordova/Ionic httpd server plugin - url not visible

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework, angularjs-controller

i have a problem with Angular controller in my Ionic/Cordova project.

Can someone explain me why url which i get in line 25: `$scope.serverURL=url;`

isn't visible in line 63 `alert($scope.serverURL);` (it return null)?

Here is my controller:

```
  var app = angular.module('iremotee');

  app.controller('StreamingController', function(ConnectSdkService, $scope, $rootScope, $state, Camera) {
      var options = {
          quality: 100,
          destinationType: 0,
          sourceType: 0,
          mediaType: 2
      };

      $scope.currentFile = null;
      $scope.httpd = null;
      $scope.serverURL = null;
      alert($scope.serverURL + "!!!");
      $scope.createHttpd = function() {
          $scope.httpd = (cordova && cordova.plugins && cordova.plugins.CorHttpd) ? cordova.plugins.CorHttpd : null;
      };

      $scope.startMediaServer = function() {

          if ($scope.httpd) {
              // before start, check whether its up or not
              $scope.httpd.getURL(function(url) {
                  if (url.length > 0) {
                      $scope.serverURL = url;
                      alert($scope.serverURL);
                  } else {
                      $scope.httpd.startServer({
                          'www_root': '/',
                          'port': 8080,
                          'localhost_only': false
                      }, function(url) {
                          $scope.serverURL = url;
                          alert($scope.serverURL);

                      }, function(error) {});
                  }

              });
          } else {}
      };

      $scope.stopServer = function() {
          if ($scope.httpd) {
              $scope.httpd.stopServer(function() {}, function(error) {});
          }
      };

      $scope.getMedia = function() {
          $state.go('mainmenu');
      };

      ionic.Platform.ready(function() {
          $scope.createHttpd();
          $scope.startMediaServer();
      });

      $scope.getFile = function() {
          alert($scope.serverURL);
          Camera.getFromMemory(options).then(function(URI) {

              if (URI.indexOf("file://") == -1) {
                  URI = "file://" + URI;
              }

              window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(URI, function(fileEntry) {
                  var URI = fileEntry.toURL();
                  var str = URI;
                  str = str.replace("file:///storage/emulated/0/", "/sdcard/");
                  str = str.replace("file:///storage/emulated/0/", "/sdcard1/");
                  str = str.replace("file:///storage", "");
                  Camera.currentURI = str;
                  alert(Camera.currentURI);
                  $scope.currentFile = Camera.currentURI;
              }); //resolveLocalFileSystemURL-END
          }, function(err) {
              alert(err);
          }); //getFromMemory-END
      }; //getFile-END

      $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
          $scope.stopServer();
      });




  });
```

Comment: Dude, no HTML, no control flow and you expect us to provide you a solution ??? Share a plunker atleast that can depict the complete development cycle.

Comment: Hi, here is my HTML and JS controller 
http://plnkr.co/edit/MbWkEgaSBKvkmE9YGuYN?p=info.

I'm using this controller only in that view. 
Here is the plugin which i'm using: https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-httpd

I want to get current url of device to get full url to file:
$scope.currentFile=$scope.serverURL+Camera.currentURI;
but $scope.serverURL is null in all the places. $scope.serverURL have any valu only in $scope.httpd.getURL(function(url)

Comment: are you sure that httpd.startserver is working?

Comment: Yes, i see my phone in browser

Comment: So you re probably calling the getfile function before startServer finished.... can't see any other reasons

Comment: I'm using getfile only after button click. Nad startServer is starting when th e window is loading.